# How can I configure EclipseLink MOXy in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, eclipselink, moxy

How can I configure [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) in Spring MVC? I have three configuration files- applicationContext.xml, rest-servlet.xml and rest-context.xml.

Comment: The following should help:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Do you know of any updated docs to support integration with Spring 4 using purely java config?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way that I know of - this is to register Moxy as the JAXB provider, just place a `jaxb.properties` file in the package where you have your JAXB annotated domain classes, with this content:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have placed `jaxb.properties` with that entry in the exact same package where you have your @XmlRootElement annotated classes. And how are you able to say that Moxy has not taken effect - do you have a breakpoint somewhere where you find the JAXBContext?

Comment: It gives me this error:
 "jaxb.properties" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
I have a jaxb.index file. I don't how to configure it with jaxb.properties

Answer (score 0):

Support for EclipseLink MOXy was enhanced in Spring 3.1.3: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9757?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab